# Spring Security 400

Tags: java, spring

if you specify incorrect data when logging in, postman gives the message "invalid data", but the status is "200 ok", I need to receive `400` status

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public Map<String, Object> performLogin(@RequestBody PersonDTO personDTO, BindingResult bindingResult) throws BadCredentialsException{

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authInputToken =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(personDTO.getUsername(),
                        personDTO.getPassword());


        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(authInputToken);
        }
        catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            return Map.of("message", "Неверные данные!");
        }

        String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(personDTO.getUsername());
        Optional<Person> person = peopleRepository.findByUsername(personDTO.getUsername());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare global exception handler, then you won't need to catch the exception in your controller at all.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(BadCredentialsException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> badCredentialsHandler() {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(Map.of("message", "invalid credentials"));
    }
}
```

Keep in mind the exception is quite general, so depending on your use case you may still need to catch and rethrow it wrapped in some custom exception and then handle the custom one.

If the exception contains information you need to build the response, or just for logging purposes, you can autowire it in the handler method.